# Google Maps navigation in Android not coming back to Recent Activity

Tags: android, google-maps

i am working with Google Maps navigation in my Android application ...

When calling Google Maps navigation's Intent from MainActivity Google Map Showing route path completely in my device but now when press back button from  Google Maps it close whole application instead go back to MainActivity so i need to go back my MainActivity on Back pressed in Map activity...

My code for calling map activity

```
String strURL = new StringBuilder()
                    .append("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=")
                    .append(src_lat).append(",").append(src_long)
                    .append("&daddr=").append(dest_lat).append(",")
                    .append(dest_long).toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(strURL));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
                    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Can any one help me ??? how to catch back pressed event from Google Maps navigation's Intent ...

Comment: Why dont u use startActivityforResult();

Comment: Already try with `startActivityforResult(); ` but `onActivityResult()` call instantly when mapactivity load ..

Comment: @BlackTiger  Would you like to stay the same page when back button pressed or anything else?

Comment: did u define your activity singleinstance or singletask?

Comment: No ... my MainActivity is not singleinstance nor singletask....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use startActivityForResult(); and make sure your activity doesn't have any propertly like singleinstance or singleTop.

Comment: The only possible way is startActivityforResult(); because you cant get a back pressed event from a third part app, I am pretty sure about it.

Comment: Ohkkk...i found the solution...i call `onUserLeaveHint()` in my main activity so when i call new intent as per my `onUserLeaveHint()`function all activity cleared now i put condition there so its working properly now also no need to use `startActivityForResult();` but your answer also helpful to me so accepted....thanks,,,